# BottomSheetDialog containing ComposeView

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to fill a bottomsheet dialog with a compose view inside an `AppCompatActivity`:

```
val bottomSheet = BottomSheetDialog(this)

bottomSheet.setContentView(ComposeView(this).apply {
    setContent {
        MaterialTheme {
            Test()
        }
    }
})

bottomSheet.show()
```

using `androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.4.0-alpha10`, `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1`

getting the following exception:

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewTreeLifecycleOwner not found from android.widget.FrameLayout{386906d V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0900d3 app:id/container}
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposer_androidKt.createLifecycleAwareViewTreeRecomposer(WindowRecomposer.android.kt:244)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposer_androidKt.access$createLifecycleAwareViewTreeRecomposer(WindowRecomposer.android.kt:1)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposerFactory$Companion$LifecycleAware$1.createRecomposer(WindowRecomposer.android.kt:99)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposerPolicy.createAndInstallWindowRecomposer$ui_release(WindowRecomposer.android.kt:155)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposer_androidKt.getWindowRecomposer(WindowRecomposer.android.kt:230)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.resolveParentCompositionContext(ComposeView.android.kt:220)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.ensureCompositionCreated(ComposeView.android.kt:227)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.onAttachedToWindow(ComposeView.android.kt:259)
        at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:19553)
...
```

Comment: Checkout my answer for similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73244967/10551651)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I ended up subclassing `BottomSheetDialogFragment` and using a compose view there:

```
class MyBottomSheet : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
    
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View = ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
            setViewCompositionStrategy(ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed)
            setContent {
                // working
            }
    }
}
```

And calling it from the activity like this:

```
val modalBottomSheet = MyBottomSheet()
modalBottomSheet.show(supportFragmentManager, "SomeTAG")
```

Just in case anyone runs into the same problem.