# Using a ComposeView inside layout or a BottomSheetDialog throws exception

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a non compose view that needs to show a BottomSheetDialog.  I would like the root view:

```
myBottomSheetDialog = BottomSheetDialog(requireActivity(), R.style.Theme_Design_BottomSheetDialog)
val bottomSheetView = BottomsheetBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, null, false)
myBottomSheetDialog.setContentView(bottomSheetView.root)
```

Where the BottomSheetBinding view is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_compose"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I open the dialog the following exception is thrown.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewTreeLifecycleOwner not found from android.widget.FrameLayout{ee8d547 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0a00c1 app:id/container}
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposer_androidKt.createLifecycleAwareViewTreeRecomposer(WindowRecomposer.android.kt:244)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposer_androidKt.access$createLifecycleAwareViewTreeRecomposer(WindowRecomposer.android.kt:1)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposerFactory$Companion$LifecycleAware$1.createRecomposer(WindowRecomposer.android.kt:99)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposerPolicy.createAndInstallWindowRecomposer$ui_release(WindowRecomposer.android.kt:155)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposer_androidKt.getWindowRecomposer(WindowRecomposer.android.kt:230)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.resolveParentCompositionContext(ComposeView.android.kt:244)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.ensureCompositionCreated(ComposeView.android.kt:251)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.onMeasure(ComposeView.android.kt:288
```

For a few reasons I cannot make the parent view compose first.  But I would like to show a dialog and use compose for the content within that dialog.

Comment: What version of Fragments are you using? Support for `ComposeView` in any `DialogFragment` subclass was added in [Fragment 1.3.1](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.3.1).

Comment: Good question, I don't specifically reference a specific version of fragment.  Is that a child dependency that comes along with something else?  Perhaps core-ktx?

Comment: I believe BottomSheetDialogFragment is coming from "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1.

Comment: Yes, AppCompat 1.4.1 depends on Fragment 1.3.6. Can you include the rest of your `BottomSheetDialogFragment`? Specifically, we need to know if that `myBottomSheetDialog` is what you are returning from the `onCreateDialog()` method.

Comment: BottomSheetDialogFragment is an android class, I am not overriding anything, onCreate is whatever the base implementation is.  Also to note, I have tested this without a ComposeView and the bottom sheet dialog works just fine.

Comment: I'm confused. The title of your question says you are using a bottom sheet fragment: that's what actually works. Are you *not* using a fragment to show your dialog?

Comment: @ianhanniballake, I have updated the title, code remains the same.  Creating a BottomSheetDialog

Comment: @lostintranslation did you find the solution. I'm also facing this issue.

Answer (score 4):

In order to use Composables as content of any window we must set view tree owners on the root of the view tree. In most of the android main classes it's done by google devs already, but for some reason they forgot about BottomSheetDialog.

Here is the solution, call setViewTreeOwners() before calling BottomSheetDialog.setContentView()

```
private fun setViewTreeOwners() {
    val activity = extractActivity(context) // if you have activity present nearby, then just use your activity here.
    val decorView = window?.decorView
    if (activity != null && decorView != null) {
        ViewTreeLifecycleOwner.set(decorView, activity as? LifecycleOwner)
        ViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner.set(decorView, activity as? ViewModelStoreOwner)
        ViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner.set(decorView, activity as? SavedStateRegistryOwner)
    }
}
```

Optional code for extracting activity from context

```
private fun extractActivity(context: Context?): Activity? {
    var currentContext = context
    while (currentContext != null) {
        if (currentContext is Activity) return currentContext
        if (currentContext !is ContextWrapper) break
        currentContext = currentContext.baseContext
    }
    return null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found workaround for BottomSheetDialog with ComposeView

```
@Composable
fun showBottomSheetDialog() {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
    val savedStateRegistryOwner = LocalSavedStateRegistryOwner.current

    val bottomSheetDialog = object : BottomSheetDialog(context) {
        override fun setContentView(view: View) {
            super.setContentView(view)

            //Workaround :/
            val fieldContainer = BottomSheetDialog::class.java.getDeclaredField("container").apply {
                isAccessible = true
            }
            val container = fieldContainer.get(this) as View
            container.setViewTreeLifecycleOwner(lifecycleOwner)
            container.setViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner(savedStateRegistryOwner)
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun BottomSheetContent() {
    //...
    }

    bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(ComposeView(bottomSheetDialog.context).apply {
    setViewCompositionStrategy(ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed)
        setContent {
            BottomSheetContent()
        }
    })

    DisposableEffect(lifecycleOwner) {
        val observer = LifecycleEventObserver { _, event ->
            if (event == Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE) {
                bottomSheetDialog.dismiss()
            }
        }
        lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.addObserver(observer)
        onDispose {
            lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.removeObserver(observer)
        }
    }

    bottomSheetDialog.show()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Before you call `setContentView`, you have to declare composition strategy first:  `setViewCompositionStrategy(ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed)`

Comment: didn't fix the issue.