# how to use Jetpack Compose in Service (Floating Window)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-service, android-lifecycle

I want to use Jetpack Compose to implement the floting window UI. But I got this error:`java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewTreeLifecycleOwner not found from androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView`
Here are my floating window service code：

```kotlin
class FloatingService : Service() {
    private lateinit var windowManager: WindowManager

    private lateinit var contentView: View

    private lateinit var layoutParams: WindowManager.LayoutParams

    // init windowManager, contentView, layoutParams
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        windowManager = getSystemService<WindowManager>()!!


        contentView = ComposeView(this).apply {
            setContent {
                Text(text = "Hello World")
            }
        }

        layoutParams = WindowManager.LayoutParams().apply {
            type = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY
            else
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE

            width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            flags =
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
            x = 0
            y = 200

            format = PixelFormat.RGBA_8888 // give window transparent background

            gravity = Gravity.TOP or Gravity.END // layout right
        }
    }

    // add contentView to windowManager
    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        windowManager.addView(
            contentView,
            layoutParams
        )
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        windowManager.removeView(contentView)
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }
}
```

I am confirm it can work good when you init `contentView` by using `Button(this)`. What's more, I have tried using `LifecycleService` which in `implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:2.5.1")` and init `ViewTreeLifecycleOwner` by using `ViewTreeLifecycleOwner.set(contentView, this)`, the result is that I got another error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Composed into the View which doesn't propagateViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner!`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using a ComposeView inside layout or a BottomSheetDialog throws exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72395779/using-a-composeview-inside-layout-or-a-bottomsheetdialog-throws-exception)

Comment: @RickyMo I don't think it's the same as this problem.  The core of this problem is how to load ComposeView inside Service, that problem not include this point. But thanks all the same.

Comment: This post might also help: [InputMethodService with Jetpack Compose - ComposeView causes: Composed into the View which doesn't propagate ViewTreeLifecycleOwner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65755763/inputmethodservice-with-jetpack-compose-composeview-causes-composed-into-the)

Comment: @RickyMo [InputMethodService with Jetpack Compose - ComposeView causes: Composed into the View which doesn't propagate ViewTreeLifecycleOwner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65755763/inputmethodservice-with-jetpack-compose-composeview-causes-composed-into-the). It is somewhat similar to my question, I have already solved it, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK. Here is my own solution

1. add this dependence:

```
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:2.5.1")
```

2. make the following changes based on the code in my question

```kotlin
import android.content.Intent
import android.view.View
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleService
import androidx.savedstate.SavedStateRegistry
import androidx.savedstate.SavedStateRegistryController
import androidx.savedstate.SavedStateRegistryOwner

// you need extends LifecycleService and implement SavedStateRegistryOwner.
class YourService() : LifecycleService(), SavedStateRegistryOwner {

    // create a SavedStateRegistryController to get SavedStateRegistry object.
    private val savedStateRegistryController = SavedStateRegistryController.create(this)

    private lateinit var contentView: View

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        // init your SavedStateRegistryController
        savedStateRegistryController.performAttach() // you can ignore this line, becase performRestore method will auto call performAttach() first.
        savedStateRegistryController.performRestore(null)

        // configure your ComposeView
        contentView = ComposeView(this).apply {
            setViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner(this@YourService)
            setContent {
                Text(text = "Hello World")
            }
        }
        ViewTreeLifecycleOwner.set(contentView, this)

        // init your WindowManager and LayoutParams
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
        // add your contentView to windowManager
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        // remove your view from your windowManager
    }

    // override savedStateRegistry property from SavedStateRegistryOwner interface.
    override val savedStateRegistry: SavedStateRegistry
        get() = savedStateRegistryController.savedStateRegistry
}
```

3. register you service and declare `android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission.

Comment: Instead ViewTreeLifecycleOwner.set(contentView, this) I used setViewTreeLifecycleOwner(this@ForegroundService) inside compose function

Comment: `Cannot access 'performRestore': it is internal in 'SavedStateRegistry'` - latest 1.2.1 version of `androidx.savedstate`

Comment: @user924 This method still public in my project at version 1.2.1. You can also check 
 it at official document [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/savedstate/SavedStateRegistryController#summary).